# AngularJS error while using ngAudio

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to play audio using AngualarJs

My HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="audioTest">
    <button ng-click="playSound()"></button>
    <script src="javascripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
     <script src="javascripts/angular.audio.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My app.js Code:

```
var app  = angular.module("test",['ngAudio']);

var audio = app.controller("audioTest",function($scope,ngAudio){
$scope.playSound = function(){
    $scope.audio = ngAudio.load("abc.wav");
   $scope.audio.play();
}
});
```

While i load page i got error in console which lead me to 
[Error Details](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=ngAudioProvider%20%3C-%20ngAudio%20%3C-%20audioTest)

Comment: Make sure your script route to `javascripts/ng-audio.min.js` is really resolving to the script

Comment: i have also tried with replacing script from  http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/

Comment: Correct name for the script seems to be "angular.audio.js" not "ng-audio.min.js"

Comment: Name of the script file doesn't matter .Still I tried but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're reporting is due to an error resolving `angular.audio.js` script that can't be found by the name `javascripts/angular.audio.js`

I made a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/en8x1nny/

This fiddle imports the script that [the original demo from ngAudio](http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/) is using.

The full path for that script is: http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/angular.audio.js.

You can download it and add it to your `javascripts` directory. Be sure not to use it by the URL mentioned above because github is not a CDN intended to serve scripts.

If you previously installed ngAudio by bower, the script should be in:

```
your_project_path/bower_components/angular-audio/app/angular.audio.js
```